# Need Xpath for Span>Class>title

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am new to testing and need some help on Xpath for following code :

[image: snapshot of the elements]

InnerHTML of the element:

```
<img class="icon" src="custom/icons/Injury.png">
<span class="buttonText"><span class="title">An injury</span></span>
<span class="title">An injury</span>
```

I want to click on "An injury", have tried below xpath but its not working

`driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='An injury']")).click();`

```
    <div id="pageLayout-eLeType-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEu0-bMs-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEuw" class="formCell button80Percent" style="width:48.0%;"> 
     <div class="dashboardLinksContainer">
      <div title="" class="dashboardLink linkAsButton">
       <a href="/QUASAR/new/Incident" onclick="userFavourites.recordVisit('Incident', 'anVtcENvbW1hbmQoJz9jb21tYW5kPW5ldyZicGlkPUFCTnlsR0dYTWpRMk9EazJNREkwTXpNNCZ0aXRsZT0iSW5jaWRlbnQiJyk7');jumpCommand('?command=new&amp;bpid=ABNylGGXMjQ2ODk2MDI0MzM4&amp;title=&quot;Incident&quot;');return false;"><img class="icon" src="custom/icons/Injury.png">
         <span class="buttonText">
           <span class="title">An injury</span>
         </span>
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>

<div id="pageLayout-eLeType-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEu3-bMs-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEuw" class="formCell button80Percent" style="width:48.0%;"> 
  <div class="dashboardLinksContainer">
    <div title="" class="dashboardLink linkAsButton">
      <a href="/QUASAR/new/Incident" onclick="userFavourites.recordVisit('Incident', 'anVtcENvbW1hbmQoJz9jb21tYW5kPW5ldyZicGlkPUFCTnlsR0dYTWpRMk9EazJNREkwTXpNNCZ0aXRsZT0iSW5jaWRlbnQiJyk7');jumpCommand('?command=new&amp;bpid=ABNylGGXMjQ2ODk2MDI0MzM4&amp;title=&quot;Incident&quot;');return false;">
         <img class="icon" src="custom/icons/Damage.png">
      <span class="buttonText"><span class="title">Damage or loss to property or asset</span>
     </span>
    </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the 2 html code and there are about 8 more and all have same span class >buttonText and Span class = title with just different title names

Comment: Can you please check, whether that particular element resides in iframe tag?

Comment: Why did you add `xpath-2.0` tag? Selenium doesn't support XPath 2.0. Also let us know which element exactly you want to click: provided HTML sample differs from HTML on attached picture

Comment: I have provided html code and I want to click on title>An injury

Comment: Did you try to click the `<a>` tag instead of the `<span>` tag? There's an inline JavaScript registered to the `<a>` tag onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector

```
span.title:nth-child(3)
```

Edit
 You can use below Xpath

```
".//*[@id='pageLayout-eLeType-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEu0-bMs-AFBWtFlqgByDxQjVusTPqEuw']/div[1]/div/a/span/span"
```

or Use Link text

```
"An injury"
```

Comment: sorry i dint understood. I have attached screenshot of my html code.

Comment: I have added code for CSS selector so you can use it instead of xpath

Comment: i tried using above CSS selector but its not working . Can u please check the screenshot attached with original post that will give more details about my html code.

Comment: Please add full HTML text instead of screenshot

Comment: i have added full HTML text

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to invoke `click()` on the element with text as **An injury** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.dashboardLink.linkAsButton > a[href='/QUASAR/new/Incident'] span.buttonText > span.title")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dashboardLink linkAsButton']/a[@href='/QUASAR/new/Incident']//span[@class='buttonText']/span[@class='title'][contains(.,'An injury')]")).click();
  ```

Comment: Hi, in css [href=/QUASAR/new/Incident]  single quotes not required?

Comment: I tried using both but still not able to click. I am able to locate the exact element by using find or search function while inspecting the element on chrome. But when i am using same code in selenium i am not able to click on that element.